# Save excel workbook as pdf

Tags: excel, vba

Hi have 50+ sheets in my excel workbook and i want to save them individual pdf files.
I also want to save them in specific folder and want to name these files from certain cell.

I got the basic of basic, saving them individually to desktop, but having trouble saving to certain folder and name part.

```
Sub Save_As_PDF_To_Desktop_4()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
 If sh.Name <> "Instructions" And sh.Visible = True Then sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & sh.Name & ".pdf" _
 , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
 :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
 Next sh
End Sub
```

Could someone assist me on this? Thanks!

Comment: Would be good to break that into smaller steps btw.

Comment: Change the `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & sh.Name & ".pdf"` part to what you need. Looks like you're naming the files as per `sh.Name`, if you need that to be a cell value then you need to read the cell's value, e.g. `sh.Range("A1").VAlue`. If you need to prompt the user for a particular folder, look into `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` - keep in mind that the user can cancel such prompts, so you should handle cancellation, too.

Comment: "having trouble saving to certain folder and name part" is a rather vague problem description. Can you [edit] to clarify exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Lets say i want to save these pdfs to my pdf folder in c drive.
C:\Users\uername\Desktop\pdf

I want to name those pdfs from cell A1

Comment: @rrrR: It should be a matter of security settings. If a custom folder created on drive  "C:\", the one with SO, is the place where you would like to save the files, you must take the ownership for it and then allow to working user full rights.

Comment: `sh.Range("A1").Value & ".pdf"` to save using the value from A1 as the file name.  @BigBen is right though - that one line does too much, and makes it difficult to test.

Comment: @BigBen and Tim thanks for helping. I am really new at this stuff and I am not quite sure how to change the CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\" & sh.Name & ".pdf" part. I did change the sh.Name to sh.Range("A1").VAlue

Comment: Try stuff, break things. What's `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")` doing? Declare a local variable `Dim exportFolder As String`, then assign it `exportFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")` - then you can have a `exportFileName` variable that would be assigned to `exportFolder & "\" & sh.Name & ".pdf"`, and then the actual export call could read like `sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Filename:=exportFileName, {rest of the parameters}`, and between each of these instructions you can break (F9) and inspect/debug/tweak the values. Welcome to programming!